# Is it possible to dynamically base arguments on a separate function using Argparse in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, argparse

This may be a bit confusing so I'll try and clarify my points with visualizations and examples

Say I have a driver code and two separate python functions.

Function A is the following:

```py
def FuncA(foo, bar):

    output = foo + bar

    return output
```

Function B is the following:

```py
def FuncB(foobar, x):

    output = (foobar)/(x) 

    return output
```

I want to create a driver code that can call either of these functions and base the arguments it parses from the user (via argparse) off of the function itself.

This means the following code is **NOT** allowed:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-function', choices=["FuncA","FuncB"])

*blah blah*

if function == "FuncA":

   parser.add_argument('-foo')
   parser.add_argument('-bar')
elif:
   parser.add_argument('-foobar')
   parser.add_argument('-x')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

or anything of a similar sort.

The point is to create what is essentially a "Plug 'n Play" system where codes can be added modularly to this driver code and modified individually (including potentially changing inputs) without having to modify the driver code itself (or with potential minimal modification to the driver code)

We are looking for a way to intelligently parse the arguments that a function has and use this to create argparse arguments for a given run case.

A visual example of what we are doing (with the context of a visualization code)

[image: Visualization of a modular system]

The ideal command-line invocation for our example would look something like this:

`python3 driverCode.py funcA -foo 10 -bar 7`

OR

`python3 driverCode.py funcB -foobar 8 -x 2`

and while this invocation could usually be accomplished with grouping, I don't believe this will handle the issue of dynamically fetching the `-foo` or `-bar` portion of the argument via the function.

Comment: Sounds like parsers that already exist in `pypi`. Some do their own parsing from scratch.  Others build on `argparse`.  Years ago I used `plac`, but I haven't kept up with it.  https://pypi.org/project/plac/

Comment: At the very least, you would have to call `parse_known_args()` first, then add function-specific arguments to the parser before calling `parse_args()`. Figuring out which arguments to add is another question entirely.

Comment: @chepner this is the sense that I'm getting. I may have found a solution that will work and will answer my own question if I do find a solution.